# QGIS won't launch on factory reset Dell with Windows 10 Home

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-10

I just acquired a Dell Inspiron laptop from a friend. It has Windows 10 Home. I did a factory reset, installed the QGIS standalone installer for 3.22.8. It installed successfully, but when I go to run it, I get the following error message (swap out version in screenshot below for the version I'm installing):

> "Oops, looks like an error loading QGIS
> Details:
> Could not load qgis_app.dll
> Windows Error: The specified module could not be found.
> Help:
> Check C:\PROGRA~\QGIS3~22.8\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.env for correct environment paths

Before I installed QGIS, I:

- Did a factory reset
- Installed all updates, including for the graphics driver
- Turned off all scanning/antivirus/firewall protections

I have attempted this twice (including another factory reset) and have gotten the same result. I have tried the OpenCL.dll fix that I have seen in several help forums, but that did not work either, because the regsvr32 command to register the .dll did not execute. That message was:

> entry-point dllregisterserver was not found

An installation of the same QGIS version on Windows 10 Enterprise works perfectly with no issues. I compared the qgis-ltr-bin.env file on both installations and they were 100% identical.

I have also attempted installing with the OSGeo4W network installer after doing a complete clean of the QGIS files from the previous install. I receive the same error message.

Is this a Windows 10 Home issue? A Dell issue? I have installed QGIS on numerous computers of various manufacturers and versions of Windows and this is the first time I have had this problem.

Comment: Please always include error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Why did you do anything with a `opencl.dll` when the error talks about `qgis_app.dll`? What things in forums do reference here?

Comment: This was my main reference with several included other links, which I found after a lot of Googling. https://qgis.nl/2021/11/05/qgis-on-windows-oops-could-not-load-qgis_app-dll-message/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

The QGIS Standalone Installers were updated with the fix on July 6 and the installation proceeded without any issues and opened correctly without any error messages.